# SQL Multiple View-On-View, then using a Union Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, view

I am UNIONISING two SQL Server intense queries together.

I am fairly new to SQL so I use multiple views to prepare the data.

```
VIEW 1                                    VIEW A
      |                                        |
VIEW 2 (Grouping View 1)                  VIEW B (Grouping View A)

              \                                /
               UNION VIEWS 2B  (JOINING VIEW 2 AND B)
                              |
                        VIEW 3 (Grouping View 2B)                    ANOTHER VIEW C
                                        \                                  /
                                        UNION VIEW 3C (JOINING VIEW 3 AND C)
```

By the time I get to View 3C there is approximately 4 million rows of data and 52 columns. When I run the View from SQL Server Management Studio, I sometimes get a 'TIME EXPIRED ERROR'. Sometimes it runs great, but it takes about 10 minutes to start outputting data.

If I run the query into a PivotTable in Excel, it sometimes runs and sometimes falls over.

The data is updated every week by Wednesday and there are approximately 30 people refreshing the data.

So again I am new at SQL and would like to know the different approaches one could suggest. Is there a intermediate set of videos out there that could assist?

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based because you have asked a generic question.  You should ask another question with more information about the specific problem you are trying to solve, including the queries you are using (perhaps simplified).

Answer (score 1):

The use of temporary tables versus more complex queries is a matter of opinion and there are benefits and downsides going both ways. SQL Server has a pretty good optimizer, so it usually does a good job optimizing complex queries. It also supports query hints (Postgres, are you listening?). In my experience, the SQL Server optimizer with occasional query hints has been sufficient for achieving performance.

On the other hand, some people are more comfortable with using temporary tables. And, when they are not used as a crutch, they can definitely be helpful.  For instance, you can build indexes on temporary tables which can greatly boost performance. Also, if you have a subqueries used multiple times in a query, then SQL Server re-creates them instead of storing the results and re-using the results (Microsoft, are you listening?). There is not even a compiler hint to materialize CTEs, for instance.

I find that using temporary tables leads to complex code. It requires assigning names to the tables and being sure that they are updated correctly when re-running the query. Over the years, I have spent many hours debugging problems caused by intermediate tables not being properly updated (which is the primary reason why I tend not to use them).

Finally, I do not think that views are the right approach. Views are compiled by the SQL engine the first time they are run. If the data changes, then the execution plan may not change -- and the query plan is then suboptimal. You need to be careful with views (as well as queries in stored procedures and functions) when the underlying data might be changing in such a way that could affect the query plan.

If you are new to SQL, then your queries are probably not that complicated and you should get experience with more complex queries.

Comment: Many thanks for the above. You raise some valid points and you are correct in closing this question as when I read it again, there needs to be more detail. Otherwise as you said the answer could be obtained in a multitude of ways. Could you recommend an intermediate SQL course. I can do Views, Queries, Joins etc. I feel like I need the next step eg like programming? Am I trying to get an answer using the wrong tool? eg SQL Queries and Views should not have calculations, and calculations should be done in yucky Excel? ;-)